# RXJava - Permanently switch observables when data is available on one of them

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have the following minimal (not) working example:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture;

@Test
public void testTest() {
    final Observable<Long> initialValues = Observable.fromArray(100L, 200L, 300L);
    final SettableFuture<Long> future = SettableFuture.create();
    final Observable<Long> newValues = Observable.fromFuture(future);

    new Thread(
            () -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                future.set(400L);
            }
    ).start();

    initialValues.takeUntil(newValues).concatWith(newValues).subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);
}
```

I was expecting the following output:

100

200

300

but the output was

400

Is there any fault in my logic? I'm trying to accomplish the following behavior:

Let there be 2 observables: A, B. Take values from A until B start publishing values, then switch exclusively on B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fromFuture` is [blocking](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#fromFuture-java.util.concurrent.Future-) the thread that subscribes to it so the `initialValues` never get a chance to run due to `takeUntil` subscribing to `newValues` first and then getting blocked. Try this:

```java
initialValues
.takeUntil(newValues.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
.concatWith(newValues)
.subscribe(System.out::println, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```